# What is a good tool to navigate large C# code base

Tags: c#

I am working on a large c# code base. I would like to know what is a good tool for code navigation? e.g. find out which class inherits a particular interface? where does this method get called?

Should I install ctags? Or Using the search in Visual Studio is already the best tool available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio includes the functionality you've specified so it sounds like a good starting option.

Once you identify a specific scenario where Visual Studio isn't providing what you need, then  I would suggest having a look around.